# Schema validation passed for a random document?

Tags: jsonschema

I'm new to JSON schema and Json.NET schema. Was just following the sample to write a test program that does a schema validation. I picked a random schema and a randome JSON file but the IsValid() call at the end returns True. Am I missing something? Thanks.

```
static void SchemaTest3()
    {
        string schemaJson = @"{
           'description': 'A person',
           'type': 'object',
           'properties': {
             'name': {'type':'string'},
             'hobbies': {
               'type': 'array',
               'items': {'type':'string'}
             }
          }
        }";
        JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

        IList<string> errorMessages;
        JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(@"{
                           '@Id': 1,
                           'Email': 'james@example.com',
                           'Active': true,
                           'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
                           'Roles': [
                             'User',
                             'Admin'
                           ],
                          'Team': {
                            '@Id': 2,
                            'Name': 'Software Developers',
                            'Description': 'Creators of fine software products and services.'
                          }
                        }");
        bool isValid = jToken.IsValid(schema, out errorMessages);
        Console.Write(isValid);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema you picked allows additional properties to be added and does not make any fields "required", that the reason any valid json will pass your schema.

If you add "additionalProperties":false this will make your schema more stricter.

You can use http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ to play with your schema and explore other options.

I found http://json-schema.org/examples.html quite useful, when starting with json schema.

Here's is your schema that is more stricter.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "description": "A person",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "hobbies": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```